# magnetic door stop for steel doors

Tags: doors

I have a refrigerator door that opens up and hits the window of a steel door. What is the best way to stop this? I have been looking at door stoppers but they all have screws to attach them which won't work in this case as I don't want to put screw holes in the steel door nor in my steel fridge. Is there such a thing as a magnet to attach to a door that can be used?

Comment: A diagram or picture of just how the door hits the window would help.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, get any old magnet & glue or screw on a Super Ball. But, if this is recent or different from how the fridge started out, then your fridge's door stop(s) is shot. This thingy.
[image: Doorstop]

These come in all different shapes & sizes & can be on the top or bottom of the fridge's doors, they commonly break. They usually fatigue where that wing meets the tab going up & look like they've been torn. You'll need to either replace it or get another run out of it by swapping it with the other door (this only works with Side by Side fridges).

If after replacement the problem is fixed but it's still too close for comfort, then you can drill holes & add more metal. However, limiting the swing **too much** will interfere with drawer & shelf removal.